# whats does "T" means in this part of code? is that a higher order function?

Tags: scala

I saw a code like this, dont understand what does "T" means over here, is that means the type you want it be? but isn't "List[String]" be the type? I'm confused, and also, is this a higher order function, can someone help me with that, thanks.

```
class AuthorizedServicesImpl[T](
    val getList: T => List[String],
   ){}
```

Comment: `T` is a type parameter. A type to be determined by context. `getList` is a function that takes a `T` and returns a `List[String]`.

Comment: @ jwvh hi, how to initialize it?  I had a class like that.
class BlacklistHelper(configure: GoldenEyeRuntimeConfiguration) {
  def getList: List[String] = {
  ***
  }}

Comment: Initialize what? The `T` parameter? It can be done at the call site but it's often left to be inferred by the compiler. Wouldn't it be better to consult tutorials on basic Scala syntax before asking on SO?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`AuthorizedServiceImpl` is a genetic class. [Generic classes](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/generic-classes.html) are classes that take a type as a parameter. In this case, `T` is the type parameter and is determined using the context. `getList` is a  function that takes a parameter of type `T` and returns a `List[String]`.

Hope this helps!!

Comment: Hi @Anand Sai, how to initialize it? I had a class like that. class BlacklistHelper(configure: GoldenEyeRuntimeConfiguration) { def getList: List[String] = { *** }